# getting Error: Invalid XSD schema NODEJS using libxmljs

Tags: node.js, xml, xsd, libxml2, libxml-js

I am getting Error: Invalid XSD schema error while running this error. What is the actual issue, I am unable to find it.

```
var libxml = require("libxmljs");
var fs = require('fs');

var xsd = fs.readFileSync('D:/XML_validation/JATS-Publishing-1-3-MathML3-XSD/JATS-journalpublishing1-3-mathml3.xsd','utf8');
var xml_valid = fs.readFileSync('2100.xml','utf8');

var xsdDoc = libxml.parseXml(xsd);
var xmlDocValid = libxml.parseXml(xml_valid);

var result = xmlDocValid.validate(xsdDoc);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: How can we tell you what's wrong with your schema without seeing your schema?

Comment: Scheme link: https://jats.nlm.nih.gov/publishing/1.3/xsd/JATS-journalpublishing1-3-mathml3.xsd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Saxon, parsing the supplied URI https://jats.nlm.nih.gov/publishing/1.3/xsd/JATS-journalpublishing1-3-mathml3.xsd directly of the web, I get errors like

```
Warning at xsd:import on line 39 column 71 of JATS-journalpublishing1-3-mathml3.xsd:
   Imported schema document standard-modules/mathml3/mathml3.xsd cannot be located:
  java.io.FileNotFoundException
  (https://jats.nlm.nih.gov/publishing/1.3/xsd/standard-modules/mathml3/mathml3.xsd)
```

That's not an answer, but it's a data point that might help you find an answer - look at the `xs:include` and `xs:import` directives.